# Azure B2C Token audience refer to own client id

Tags: c#, .net, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

As the title say i am currently acquiring a token in my .net 6 console app, but the audience is reffering to itself when it should be referring to another application. I am using a custom policy for login and signup, that i am also using on my 3 SPA sites where it is working as expected.
Here is the code in the console application:

```
string clientId = "<clientID>";
string authority = "https://<custom_login_dns>/tfp/<TenantId>/B2C_1A_SIGNUP_SIGNIN";
string redirecturi = "http://localhost:3000";
string[] scopes = new string[] {
    "openid", "profile", "offline_access",
    "https://<resourcename>/<apiname>/tasks.read",
    "https://<resourcename>/<apiname>/tasks.write"
};
var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.
            Create(clientId).
            WithAuthority(authority).
            WithRedirectUri(redirecturi).
            Build();

var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
AuthenticationResult result;
try
{
    result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync();
}
catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
{
    result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
}
```

And the api permissions in app registration

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I registered a new application for the API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have one application named **`B2C API app`** where I exposed **API scopes** as below:

[image]

Now, I registered one Azure AD B2C application named **`ClientB2C`** and added **API permissions** in it:

[image]

When I ran your code in my environment, it asked me to **sign in** interactively with below screen:

[image]

After completing the authentication, I got **access token** successfully in response like this:

```cs
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

string clientId = "e05c1257-585e-4fd2-ae70-xxxxxxxxx";
string authority = "https://srib2caadtenant.b2clogin.com/tfp/360d9b86-d102-41e4-871f-xxxxxxxxx/B2C_1A_SIGNUP_SIGNIN";
string redirecturi = "http://localhost:3000";
string[] scopes = new string[] {
    "openid", "profile", "offline_access",
    "https://srib2caadtenant.onmicrosoft.com/b2cApi/tasks.read",
    "https://srib2caadtenant.onmicrosoft.com/b2cApi/tasks.write"
};
var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.
            Create(clientId).
            WithAuthority(authority).
            WithRedirectUri(redirecturi).
            Build();

var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
AuthenticationResult result;
try
{
    result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault()).ExecuteAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Access token: {0}", result.AccessToken);
}
catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
{
    result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Access token: {0}", result.AccessToken);
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I decoded the above token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) website, I got **`aud`** and **`scp`** claims with **right** values:

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked API application(client) ID in Portal where it has same value as below:

[image]

In your case, check if you are using **API application** itself to acquire token. To **reproduce** your use case, I added permissions in API application itself like below:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** by passing API application ID in **`clientId`** parameter like below:

[image]

When I decoded the token, I too got audience referred to **own client id** where **`azp`** and **`aud`** claims are same as below:

[image]